# How to add a fixed top toolbar to editorjs

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I want to add a fixed top toolbar to my editorjs like:
[image]

I do not find any documentation how to do it on: https://editorjs.io/

Of course, i already googled it, but not really a good result.

To make the toolbar is not an issue, as you can see on the screenshot.
But i don't know how i can handle, when i click on the button, that the focused block will be formatted.

Does anyone knows how I can do that?

Comment: No, i switched to tiptap

Comment: I was also looking for the exact implementation and it's a bit hard to achieve that, so I switched to https://lexical.dev